# VNC plugin not working in Remmina

Tags: plugins, vnc, remmina

Remmina 0.9.99.1, Ubuntu 14.04.

I installed Remmina from the repository. Also installed both the RDP and the VNC plugins from the repository. I have verified that remmina-plugin-vnc.so is in /usr/lib/remmina/plugins/

When I start Remmina, I see only the plugins for RDP, nothing for VNC.

Connecting to a remote host using RDP works just fine. Of course, if I try to connect to a remote host that requires the VNC protocol, I cannot, Remmina won't work in that case.

I've tried all kinds of solutions, but nothing's worked so far. I've tried complete removal and reinstallation, restarting Remmina, restarting the computer, etc.

(I originally asked this question on the "issues" GitHub page for Remmina, but they closed the question and told me that they wouldn't address it, that I had to ask it here.)

Please help me with this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

In case others come across this post.  Remmina used to come with RDP and VNC options, now they are plugins.

After you install the plugins it's not enough to just close and reopen remmina.  I think something gets left open, so you may need to kill a task or simply reboot.

```
ps -A | grep remmina
  4853 ?        00:01:15 remmina
kill 4853   #the process ID from above
```

So here's how to get everything going:

```
#to install remmina
sudo apt-get install remmina

# get the other mode plugins
sudo apt-get install remmina-plugin-vnc
sudo apt-get install remmina-plugin-rdp

# probably not needed
sudo apt-get install freerdp
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev
```

FYI: the plugins install to /usr/lib/remmina/plugins

Answer (score 6):

you can find the bug's report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1353353) and the user [Raony Guimarães](https://launchpad.net/~raonyguimaraes-gmail) gave next [solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remmina/+bug/1353353/comments/5):

> ```
> sudo apt-get install libvncclient0
> sudo remmina
> ```
>
> for some reason I still need to use sudo in order to use vnc with
>   remmina

It works for me, and after do that, I can start remmina without `sudo` and connect a remote pc through vnc protocol without any issue.

Be [warned](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remmina/+bug/1353353/comments/6), however:

> If you started remmina with sudo, then remmina creates config files
>   with root ownership. You can chown permissions back from root to your
>   user, then use without sudo.

Comment: With me it worked without sudo, but i had to kill the process using `killall remmina`

Answer (score 4):

Fixed by reinstalling:

```
sudo apt-get purge libvncserver0
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install remmina-plugin-vnc
```

[source](https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/issues/768#issuecomment-186567100)

Comment: Yes, this is the correct solution for Ubuntu 14.04+. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remmina/+bug/1353353 comments 7-8